# Testing for, testing of

Tags: prepositions

Does a laboratory do "testing for" or "testing of" a disorder? E.g., testing for/of a mutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether they're testing to determine if something exists, which would be: "...testing for..." or if they're actually testing the condition itself: "...testing of...".

It's (sort of) like the difference between "Looking for my cat" and "Looking at my cat".

Comment: A more direct comparison would be *buying (food) **for** your cat* vs *the buying **of** your cat*.